# TypeError a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' (Pydub)

Tags: python, ffmpeg, typeerror, pydub

I'm getting:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

When I run the following code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import which

AudioSegment.converter = which('ffmpeg')
AudioSegment.ffmpeg = r"C:\PATH_Programs\bin\ffmpeg.exe"

audio = AudioSegment(r'C:\Users\jack_l\Documents\Cm - 120 BPM.wav') #ERROR HERE
```

What I know:

- I have ffmpeg on my path (also set in code)
- I'm running python 3.9.13 and pydub version 0.25.1
- Error happens with or without the `AudioSegment.converter` and `AudioSegment.ffmpeg` lines – I just have them there to show I've tried that.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message seems pretty straightforward : `AudioSegment` class constructor is expecting a bytes object and you are passing a String instead.

According to the [pydub doc](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub), you could simply call `from_wav()` method by passing your filepath as a string.

Example (from the doc) :

```py
song = AudioSegment.from_wav("never_gonna_give_you_up.wav")
```

Comment: Oh my god idk how I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`AudioSegment.__init__()` takes a data parameter, not a filename parameter. Looks like you need to use `AudioSegment.from_wav()` instead.